# install detectron2 package on Docker

Tags: python, linux, windows, detectron, pycocotools

I am using the python 3.7.9 version. The dectron2 is not installed properly.
command:
docker exec -it 1ee02b74a599 /bin/bash
root@1ee02b74a599:/app# **pip install detectron2==0.2.1 -f  https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cpu/torch1.4/index.html**

the below issue occurred during the installation.

```
  *Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/conda/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nmjk8ssb/pycocotools/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nmjk8ssb/pycocotools/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-x7z500uh
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nmjk8ssb/pycocotools/
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  copying pycocotools/mask.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  copying pycocotools/cocoeval.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  copying pycocotools/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  copying pycocotools/coco.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  running build_ext
  cythoning pycocotools/_mask.pyx to pycocotools/_mask.c
  /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/pip-install-nmjk8ssb/pycocotools/pycocotools/_mask.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/common
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycocotools
  gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I./common -I/opt/conda/include/python3.7m -c ./common/maskApi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/./common/maskApi.o -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools*
```

Comment: Please tell the base image.

Comment: kkndemoacr.azurecr.io/kkn/worker-with-model:2020-01-21

Answer (score 0):

please check the python image that you use in your Dockerfile, maybe The reason you're seeing this error is that you're using the alpine or slim image which removes gcc to keep it as small as possible, then use the images like python:3.7 or ...